# sum of field in different id's

Tags: mysql

```
Table frounds:

ID   |  oname                         | fraised
----- ------------ -----------------------------
1    | linkedcare                     | $15,000,000
2    | Shankai Sports International   | $45,000,000
3    | Puma                           | $95,000,000
4    | Nike Women                     | $75,000,000
```

**PHP Code**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT SUM(fraised) AS SUM FROM frounds'); 
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row1['SUM'];    
echo $sum;
```

Above out put is '0'

**What I want result**

the sum of 'fraised' field as an example here '230,000,000' 
but I get output is '0'

Where I wrong?

Comment: what is the data type of `fraised`?

Comment: Summing strings leads to unexpected results. And second - it's a bad idea to call a field same as function.

Comment: varchar(100), may I change to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that.

**First :** If you want to keep the format of `fraised` in your table then use php code to do sum for you.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT fraised FROM frounds');
$sum = 0;
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sum += str_replace('$','',$row1['fraised']);
}
echo $sum;
```

**Second :** change the data type in table to `int` in that case you can not store data in `$15,000,000` format but you can use [php number format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to show the data in desire format

Comment: Doing the sum in PHP is not desirable.  This is something which should be done in the database most likely.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I have explained both of the ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not best practice, but you can strip the currency symbol and commas, cast `fraised` to a number, and then sum:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(fraised, 2), ',', '') AS UNSIGNED)) AS SUM
FROM frounds;
```

Moving forward, use a number column, possibly decimal, to store your currency information.  You should view the above query as a temporary hack until you can fix your table design.

### Demo

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '') AS UNSIGNED)) AS SUM FROM f' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: @gautambose Missing comma

Answer (score 0):

Because you using a `string` instead of a `number`.you have to change the data type or need to remove `$` and `,` from the string instead.
Query:

```
SELECT SUM(cast(REPLACE(substring(fraised,2),',','') as decimal)) AS SUM FROM frounds;
```

you can use the following code :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(cast(REPLACE(substring(fraised,2),',','') as decimal)) AS SUM FROM frounds;"); 
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row1['SUM'];    
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it will work for you

```
select SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(fraised,'$',''), ',' , '')) as sum from frounds
```

After updating you query your code will be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'select SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(fraised,'$',''), ',' , '')) as sum from frounds'); 
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row1['sum'];    
echo $sum;
```

**Reason:** you are getting zero due to the datatype of your column `fraised` which have values in the following format `'$15,000,000'`. In my solution, I relaced `$` and `comms`.